# Building a COUNTIFS Formula Dynamically - Troubleshooting Syntax

Tags: vba, excel

Thank you very much for all the help in the past.  I have 2 days to complete my project, and so I do not have time on my side.  I am trying to build a "COUNTIF" formula.  Building this formula is embedded in a loop because it is counting entries down columns (i.e., building sub-totals). The formula checks for the following: (1) nonblank entries for each column in "iCol" that *also* correspond to (2) the word "Verification" in column 5 ("vCol").

When I built this as a COUNTA function, it worked.  Unfortunately, it summed all the subtotals, which is why I need to do the extra check and use a "COUNTIF" formula (I think).

Well, what I have and have been troubleshooting for the past 4 hours is:

```
For groups = 1 To i ' Level 3 grouping
    Range(Cells(Start(groups), 1), Cells(Finish(groups), 1)).Rows.Group
    For iCol = 24 To 136
         Set rStart = Sheet1.Cells(Start(groups), iCol)
         Set rEnd = Sheet1.Cells(Finish(groups), iCol)
         Set vStart = Sheet1.Cells(Start(groups), vCol) 'verification column
         Set vEnd = Sheet1.Cells(Finish(groups), vCol)  'verification column
         rStart.Offset(-1, 0).Formula = _
         "=COUNTIFS(" & rStart.Address & ":" & rEnd.Address & ",""<>" _ 
         & Chr(0) & "," & vStart.Address & ":" & vEnd.Address & ",""Verification"")"

         ' old formula worked... "=COUNTA(" & rStart.Address & ":" & rEnd.Address & ")"
    Next
Next
```

I continue to get the helpful "Object/Application Error."  So I think the syntax is wrong, but for the life of me, I cannot see where.  I cannot take it out and paste it in the spreadsheet for troubleshooting since it has variables I set in the code.  Does anyone see anything glaringly obvious?  I'll take any suggestions gladly and with heartfelt thanks!

Comment: Ouch.  Please accept my sincerest apologies.  I truly am so very grateful for all the help everyone has provided.  I honestly did not know about the "good habits."  I'll do these retroactively now.  I am truly, truly sorry.  I just did not know.

Comment: About dividing the subtotals... I did not think of that one.  I have many layers of subtotals, but I don't think it would be hard to figure out how to do it by dividing.  Thanks so much for the suggestion!  If I run out of time troubleshooting the syntax, I'll definitely give that a try!

Comment: @Aerogal31, thank you, my first comment is no valid any more therefore I deleted it...

Answer (score 2):

Whenever in doubt, use the Immediate window to debug your statement. I did the same

In the below example I am hard coding the values for `rStart` **(A2)**, `rEnd` **(B2)**, `vStart` **(C2)** and `vEnd` **(D2)** for ***demonstration*** purpose

See this screenshot.

[image]

You will notice that we are missing a Double quote.

Now try this

[image]